# Weird white border behind dialog

Tags: java, android

I have a weird problem with my Android app. Some time ago I noticed that sometimes behind dialogs there is a weird white border:

[image: a busy cat]

The problem exist in both emulator and on my phone. Border seems to disappear after showing few dialogs. It's visible in both my custom dialogs fragment and on dialogs on preference screen.

I am not using support library (11 is my minimum sdk). My phone and emulator run on Android 4.0.4.

Anyone know what is going on?

EDIT:
An example code of one of dialogs:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    Bundle arguments = getArguments();

    String message = arguments.getString(MESSAGE_BUNDLE_KEY);
    if (message == null) {
        message = getString(R.string.please_wait);
    }

    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_progress, null);
    TextView messageTextView = (TextView) dialogView
            .findViewById(R.id.progress_dialog_message);
    messageTextView.setText(getString(R.string.please_wait));
    messageTextView.setTypeface(activity.getRedkneeFont());
    setRetainInstance(true);

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(dialogView)
            .create();
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_dialog_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress_dialog_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/progress_dialog_progress_bar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progress_dialog_progress_bar"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/progress_dialog_margin_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progress_dialog_progress_bar"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:background="@color/separator_blue" />
```

EDIT:
When I switched to Support Library (all fragments are now imported from appcompat), the border disappeared. A bug?

Comment: post some code of you dialog

Comment: ok, posted in original post

Comment: Code of R.layout.dialog_progress?

Comment: post the xml for `R.layout.dialog_progress`

Comment: done, posted in post

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply theme on your Dialog constructor to Translucent

setStyle(R.style.Theme.AppCompat.Translucent);

Comment: I am not using AppCompat, but i tried call setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.AppTheme);. Nothing changed

Comment: Then use direct Translucent theme "Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar"

Comment: setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar); nothing changes...

Comment: dialogView.setBackgroundColor(); change to transparent color

Comment: still nothing. I'll try using support library, it's work around, but I hope it will work